# Some problems when building Vim from source locally

Tags: original-vim

I want to enable `python3` flag in vim and because I am not the sysadmin, I tried to build Vim from source. The basic procedure is

```
Download vim source file
./configure --enable-python3interp --prefix=/home/user
make
make install
```

and everything is fine.

However, when I use vim to open a file, it gives me error:
`vim: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.8.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: What operating system are you using? I assume it's some flavor of Linux. So let's start with the usual stuff: do you have a `libpython3.8.so.1.0` anywhere? Maybe it's only the symlink that's missing. Also, did you check the usual stuff like `ldd vim`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `/etc/ld.so.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my notes for installing vim via source on debian/ubuntu, I'm guessing you need `libpython3-dev`, you need the other relevant `-dev` packages if you want to support say ruby or similar.

```sh
# WARNING: vim caches ./configure results ALWAYS run "make distclean" AFTER each OPTION added or DEPENDENCY INSTALLED!

# --with-features=big is the least for +termguicolors 24bit truecolor support
# --with-features=huge is needed for profiling
# http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vimfeat.html

# debian dependencies
apt-get install -y gcc libncurses-dev build-essential make python3 libpython3-dev xorg-dev

git pull
version=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags)
version=${version:1}

echo $version

make clean distclean

# for lua to work (in debian):
sudo apt install libluajit-5.1-dev liblua50-dev luajit
sudo ln -s /usr/include/lua50 /usr/include/lua
sudo ln -s /usr/include/luajit-2.1 /usr/include/luajit

./configure --with-features=big --with-x --disable-darwin --disable-xsmp --disable-xsmp-interact --disable-netbeans --disable-gtktest --disable-icon-cache-update --disable-desktop-database-update --disable-acl --disable-gpm --disable-sysmouse --disable-nls --enable-multibyte --enable-rubyinterp=yes --enable-python3interp=yes --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/ --enable-perlinterp=yes --enable-luainterp=yes --with-luajit --enable-cscope --enable-terminal --prefix=/usr/local

make
sudo checkinstall --docdir='/usr/local/share/vim/vim90/doc' --showinstall=no --pkgname=vim --pkgversion=$version -y

sudo apt-mark hold vim
sudo apt-remove vim-common vim-runtime vim-doc
```

Here's how I update it from latest passing build:

```sh
alias upgrade_vim='commit=$(curl -s -H "Accept: \
  application/vnd.github.antiope-preview+json" \
  "https://api.github.com/repos/vim/vim/actions/runs\
  ?status=success&actor=brammool&page=1"| \
  jq -r -e ".workflow_runs[0] | .head_sha") \
  git -C ~/src/pkg/vim fetch && cd ~/src/pkg/vim/ && \
  version=$(git describe --abbrev=0 --tags) && version=${version:1} && \
  git fetch && git checkout $commit \
  && make clean distclean; ./configure \
  --with-features=huge --with-x --disable-darwin --disable-xsmp \
  --disable-xsmp-interact --disable-netbeans --disable-gtktest \
  --disable-icon-cache-update --disable-desktop-database-update \
  --disable-acl --disable-gpm --disable-sysmouse \
  --disable-nls --enable-multibyte --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
  --enable-python3interp=yes \
  --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
  --enable-perlinterp=yes --enable-luainterp=yes --with-luajit \
  --enable-cscope --enable-terminal --prefix=/usr/local \
  && make && sudo checkinstall \
  --docdir="/usr/local/share/vim/vim90/doc" --showinstall=no --pkgname=vim \
  --pkgversion=$version -y \
  && sudo apt-mark hold vim && cd -'
```